# Why is my "gcloud beta run services replace" command failing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-endpoints

I have this YAML (with the parts in square brackets replaced with the correct content):

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ty-platform
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/[project name]/endpoints-runtime-serverless:[site URL]-2020-03-20r8
        env:
          - name: ESPv2_ARGS
            value: ^++^--cors_preset=basic++--cors_allow_origin=[site]++--cors_allow_headers="Authorization"
```

which I try to upload with this command

`gcloud beta run services replace service_replace.yaml --platform managed --region us-central1`

(after having already deployed successfully with `gcloud run deploy`).

The command runs successfully but upon testing it's clear that the replacement has failed. Namely, the ESPv2_ARGS variable is not created or updated. What could I be doing wrong?

The service in question is an ESPv2 image for a Cloud Endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried adding your `ESPv2_ARGS` as-is (using an existing Cloud Run service not Endpoints) and the service's environment **is** updated. This appears to work-as-intended.

The prior revision of the service had no environment variables defined.

```sh
gcloud beta run services describe ${SERVICE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--platform=managed \
--region=${REGION} \
--format="yaml(spec.template.spec.containers[0].env)"

  null

gcloud beta run services replace service.yaml
--platform=managed \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [...] in project [...] region [...]
✓ Deploying... Done.                                                                                                                                                           
  ✓ Creating Revision...                                                                                                                                                       
  ✓ Routing traffic...                                                                                                                                                         
Done.

gcloud beta run services describe ${SERVICE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--platform=managed \
--region=${REGION} \
--format="yaml(spec.template.spec.containers[0].env)"

spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ESPv2_ARGS
          value: ^++^--cors_preset=basic++--cors_allow_origin=[site]++--cors_allow_headers="Authorization"
```

using:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ...
        env:
        - name: ESPv2_ARGS
          value: ^++^--cors_preset=basic++--cors_allow_origin=[site]++--cors_allow_headers="Authorization"
```

I can't attest to whether this environment variable affects ESP but, the replace command appears to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately I still couldn't solve the problem, but that helped me rule out a potential cause (the environment variable not being replaced)

Comment: You're welcome! Please update your question with the outstanding issue(s) and I'll take another run at it. I've been developing some gRPC Cloud Run stuff and would be interested to try this new Endpoints' ESP